# How to relevel the levels of a factor variable without transforming it to integer in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to transform the four categories below to two new categories: `zona_a` contains `(north_east & nothern_central)` and `zone_b` contains the other two categories. Is there a way to achieve that without going through the hassle of transforming the variable to integer and using the `ifelse` function?

```
library(plm)
data("Males")

table(Males$residence)

 rural_area      north_east  nothern_central           south 
     85             733             964            1333
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have one `tidyverse` solution, hope that helps:

```
library(tidyverse)
Males <- Males %>% 
  mutate(residence = factor(case_when(residence %in% c("north_east", "nothern_central") ~ "zone_a",
                                      residence %in% c("rural_area", "south") ~ "zone_b")))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `levels()` function is one way to approach this since it allows you to set new factor levels. You can also do something similar with the `labels` argument in `factor()` (not shown).

If using `levels()` you have to take care to set the new levels based on the current order so I always take a look at them first.

Here's an example:

```r
# Check current levels
levels(Males$residence)
#> [1] "rural_area"      "north_east"      "nothern_central" "south"

# Set new levels in correct order
levels(Males$residence) = c("zone_b", "zone_a", "zone_a", "zone_b")

# Check that this worked
table(Males$residence)
#> 
#> zone_b zone_a 
#>   1418   1697
```

A "safer" method, where you explicitly have to pair the old and new values, can be done via package **forcats** using `fct_collapse()`. (Thanks to @camille for pointing this functions over `fct_recode()`.)

```r
library(forcats)
data(Males)
Males$residence = fct_collapse(Males$residence,
             zone_a = c("north_east", "nothern_central"),
             zone_b = c("rural_area", "south")
)

table(Males$residence)
#> 
#> zone_b zone_a 
#>   1418   1697
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: `fct_collapse` lets you do those reassignments with vectors, rather than writing out all the pairs of values